# VB 2010 chop off part of string and get string up to next '\' in filepath

Tags: string, vb.net, get, filepath

I cannot find a solution as how to chop off part of a string(filepath) and use what's left to get another string.

For example: if I have filepath: Q:\2456_blah_blah\file.txt and I want to put this entire filepath into an array and delete from left characters 0 through 8 (which is consistent for my application) so I'd have 'blah_blah\file.txt' left for my array.

(The blah_blah portion is going to be a dynamic length, but it will always be letters.)

So then I'd like to take the 'blah_blah\file.txt' and pull just from that beginning up to the next '\' symbol, getting "blah_blah" as a string.  I'm not too savy with VB strings at this point, so any help would be much appreciated.  This is just my thinking how it could be done, if there's a simpler solution, I'm all ears.

Thanks,

Comment: Is the portion of your string you are deleting always going to be index 0 through 8 or will that be changing from string to string as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `Substring` calls should do it.

```
Dim str As String = "Q:\2456_blah_blah\file.txt"
str = str.Substring(8, str.Length - 8)
Dim blah As String = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("\"))
```

Comment: What happens if the filename is more than 8 characters or the number in the path goes into the 10 thousands? Granted, the OP stated that the first portion of his string up to 8 characters is consistent, but did not say that the filename is a consistent length.

Comment: @vane - Not sure I follow. The length of the string is taken into consideration so it makes no difference how long the path or filename is. If the `8` becomes variable, despite what OP has said, then it can be replaced as a variable that a method takes in.

Comment: I tried it with multiple variations of filepaths, and it wokrs great. Thanks again.

Comment: @keyboardP You're right, my mistake, the long filename would not have an impact on its functionality. However, if the start of the string goes into the 10 thousands or changes for some reason this will fail. Try the string "q:\10000_blah_blah\file.txt"

Comment: @vane - But that wasn't the question. OP asked for a very specific part of the filepath. Had OP said that this is one of a variety of filepaths, or that 8 was variable, the answer would be more generic. Your answer assumes that an underscore is always the delimiter, and it would fail if the path was `Q:\10000\blah_blah\file.txt`.

Comment: @keyboardP You're right, I was just pointing that out. I don't feel it's an issue with your solution since it does what was requested, I feel that it's an issue with the design which stems from the request to begin with. To me it just seems like a pseudo-"hardcoded" design and that if it can be done to account for all variable string lengths then why not do it that way. Again, not an issue with your code or implementation but rather one with the request.

Comment: @vane No that's a very fair comment. Creating a generic method can save a lot of hassle down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this. Not knowing all the details makes it difficult to create something that fits your needs but I'll give it a shot. This will return back the blah_blah portion of your strings no matter how large "blah_blah" is, no matter how long the filename is, no matter how long the first portion of your string is and no matter how deep the path goes.

```
Dim test As String = "c:\34242_blah_blah\test.txt"

Dim startPos As Integer = test.IndexOf("_") + 1
Dim endPos As Integer = test.IndexOf("\", startPos)
Dim result As String = test.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos)
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like the 'start' & 'end' because they're not declared, am I missing a reference?

Comment: lol, I'm very sorry. I wrote this in c#, let me change it to vb. My mistake